# How to pass input from HTML forms using express.router.post

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm using express and nodejs to build a mysql CRUD app, but get stuck when I tried to post the user input from HTML forms.
Here's some of my code.

species.js

```
router.post('/addSpecies', (req, res) => {
    let name = req.body.species_name;
    let message = '';
    let nameQuery = "SELECT * FROM `species` WHERE name = '" + name +"'";
    db.query(nameQuery, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        if (result.length > 0) {
            message = 'Species already exists.';
            res.render('list_species', {message: message});
        } else {
            let query = "INSERT INTO `species` (name, updatedAt, createdAt) VALUES ('" +
                name + "',NOW() ,NOW())";
            let tableQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" + name +
                "` (`chr` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, `chromStart` INT NOT NULL, `chromEnd` INT NOT NULL, `sequence` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, `length` INT, `strand` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL)";
            db.query(query, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                db.query(tableQuery, (err, result) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return res.status(500).send(err);
                    }
                    res.redirect('/species');
                })
            })
        }
    })
})
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addSpecies" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addSpecies" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="addSpecies">Add new species</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="add-species-form" action="/species/addSpecies" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="species_name" class="col-form-label">Species name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="species_name" id="species_name" required>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success ">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.js

```
app.use('/species', speciesRouter);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static('/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Sorry for the bad coding.
When I clicked the submit button the page gave no answer, neither did the js console.log, and I'm confused where the problem is.
I'm new to javascript. Did I miss something? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: add the full url `<form action="http://localhost:8080/example">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button type/name `Submit` might be confusing you.

The `Submit` outside `<form>` tag is nothing but any other simple button without having any significance.

Keep the `Submit` button inside `form` tag similar to [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit)